# How to use substring when using powershell select-object

Tags: xml, powershell, substring

I'm wondering if there is a way to use do a substring when using powershell's select-object cmdlet

Here is an example of what i'm trying to do

```
$sapFile = "C:\MyFile*.XML"

# Get the newest xml file
$newestFile = Get-ChildItem -Path $sapFile | Sort CreationTime | Select -Last 1

# get the contents of the xml file
[XML]$sapContent = Get-Content -Path $newestFile.FullName

$sapContent.DATA.CP | Select -Property CP_NO,MEN.Substring(0,4)
```

This however doesn't work.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can create a property on the fly using `Select` that has a calculated value by using a hashtable. In the following example I select the 'CP_NO' property, and create the 'MENSubString' property with a hashtable.

```
Select -Property CP_NO,@{label='MENSubString';expression={$_.MEN.Substring(0,4)}}
```

Label can be shortened to just 'l' and Expression can be shortened to just 'e', which would look like:

```
Select -Property CP_NO,@{l='MENSubString';e={$_.MEN.Substring(0,4)}}
```

Answer (score 1):

other method :

```
$sapContent.DATA.CP | foreach {
       [pscustomobject]@{
        CP_NO=$_.CP_NO
        PartOfMen=MEN.Substring(0,4)           
       }
      }
```